# Input field always sending null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 3 input fields(User name, email & password) in my registration form. All of them are mandatory. But it looks like User Name field is always sending null value to controller and I'm getting unexpected validation message. Any help would be appreciated. P.S. rest 2 fields are just fine

HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Registration", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Registration Form</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name,Email,Password")] UserRegistration userRegistration)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserSet.Add(userRegistration);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View("Index");
        }

        return View(userRegistration);
    }
```

Comment: In model you have a UserName property, but you Include a property called Name and not one named UserName

Comment: change binding in the controller to `UserName,Email,Password"` (for the reasons given by @Steve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you need to change the Bind annotation to include a UserName and not a Name property

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserName,Email,Password")] UserRegistration userRegistration)
```

When you use the [Bind Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.include(v=vs.118).aspx) you define a list of property names for which the mvc engine should allow (include) the binding. The UserRegistration model has clearly a property named UserName and this property is not allowed in the binding list of names